# How to know what ip is listening certain udp port

Tags: android, sockets, udp

I have 2 Android apps, one is the server, and the other is the client. Both communicate each other by udp sockets, in both ways. What i need to do is in the client app, a method to check what ip from my local network is listening to my specific port (to set this ip as server ip).

Do i need to implement some kind of method in the server to return an upd package when certaing message is received (the "test" message), and shoot every single ip from my local network until one responde? or  there is a better approach?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Have the server publish its listening IP:Port somewhere that the client can read it from.
2. Have the client send a single UDP packet to the broadcast IP address of the desired network subnet.  Presumably the server is on that same subnet, so it can receive that packet and respond back to the client directly.  Then both parties will have each other's IP:port values.

Either way, there is no need to have the client send a packet to every IP on the network manually.